Characterizing cofinite submonoids of $\langle \mathbb{N}, + \rangle$?
A set $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is a submonoid of $\langle \mathbb{N}, + \rangle$ when $0 \in S$ and $S$ is closed under addition (that is, $m+n \in S$ whenever $m$ and $n$ are). For example, $\mathbb{N}$ itself and $\{0\}$ are submonoids.
This becomes more interesting when we look at examples that are cofinite (sets whose complement relative to $\mathbb{N}$ is finite). For example, the following sets are all submonoids:

$\mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$
$\mathbb{N} \setminus \{1, 3\}$
$\mathbb{N} \setminus \{1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 11, 12\}$

Given a set of the form $\mathbb{N} \setminus T$, it’s algorithmically straightforward to determine whether the set is a submonoid. First check if it contains 0, then check if any element of $T$ is the sum of two terms both not in $T$, then check up to the product of the terms in $T$ to see if each number is a nonnegative linear combination of terms not in $T$. This might take a while, though, since it’s related to the Frobenius coin problem and several related NP-hard problems.
My question is whether there is some other more “obvious” way to tell if such a set is a submonoid. Is there a simple characterization of such sets?

A submonoid of $\mathbb{N}$ is cofinite if and only if its gcd is $1$. Every nonzero submonoid of $\mathbb{N}$ is isomorphic to the cofinite submonoid formed by dividing all its elements by the gcd.

@GeoffreyTrang Let’s take $\mathbb{N} \setminus {1, 9}$. If I’m interpreting your comment correctly, this should be a submonoid of $\mathbb{N}$, but I don’t believe it is. Can you clarify?

Of course, $S=\mathbb{N} \setminus {1,9}$ is not a submonoid because $2,7 \in S$, but $2+7=9 \notin S$.  But my comment says nothing about subsets that are not submonoids. To clarify, the comment says that if $T$ is a submonoid, then $T$ is cofinite if and only if $\gcd(T)=1$ (bold for emphasis).

Oh, yes, sorry! I saw the if and only if but then missed the submonoid part. D’oh!
